# Postgres - bind results of equal type by year - long to wide data

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table

Please excuse my not very propper way of asking this as i am new to postgres...

Having the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE pub (
   id int
 , time timestamp
);

     id                time
1     1 2010-02-10 01:00:00
2     2 2011-02-10 01:00:00
3     3 2012-02-10 01:00:00
```

And

```
CREATE TABLE val (
   id int
 , type text
 , val int
);

     id  type   val
1     1     A     1
2     1     B     2
3     1     C     3
4     2     A     4
5     2     B     5
6     3     D     6
```

I would like to get the following output (for `id <= 2` )

```
   type   2010   2011
1     A      1      4
2     B      2      5
3     C      3   NULL
```

So `type` is the superset of all type's present in table *val*.
NULL meaning that there is no value for label C.
Ideally the column-headings are are years of the time. Alternatively the id itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exists at least two ways to do this.

If your table have not many categories you can use CTE

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT type,
           sum(val) FILTER (WHERE date_part('year', time) = 2010) AS "2010",
           sum(val) FILTER (WHERE date_part('year', time) = 2011) AS "2011"
    FROM pub AS p JOIN val AS v ON (v.id = p.id)
    GROUP BY type
) 
SELECT * FROM x
WHERE "2010" is NOT NULL OR "2011" IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY type
;
```

But if you have many or dynamic categories you must use crosstab:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;

SELECT * FROM crosstab(
     $$
         SELECT type,
                date_part('year', time)::text as time,
                sum(val) AS val
           FROM pub AS p JOIN val AS v ON (v.id = p.id)
       GROUP BY type, 2 
       ORDER BY 1, 2
     $$,
     $$VALUES ('2010'::text), ('2011'), ('2012') $$
     ) AS ct (type text, "2010" int, "2011" int, "2012" int);
;
```